# Foreach going out of bounds while searching through array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, textbox

The purpose of my program is to take a data txt file and edit it, and/or make additions and subtractions to it.
The text file format is like this:

```
Name|Address|Phone|# of people coming|isRSVP
```

The code I have seems to be doing it's job all the way up until I try to click one of the names within a *listbox* and it needs to search through the multidimensional array to pull information out and place within a set of *textboxes* where they can be edited. The problem is that the *foreach* loop I use gives me an *out of bounds* exception.  I tried to do a step into debug  to make sure the data is correct in the array and see the process.  Everything seems to do correctly but for some reason in the conditional statement `person[0]==listbox1.selectedIndex`   isn't returning true even though both are the same as I seen through the step into process. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
This is my code:

```
StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();
static  string txtList= "guest_list.txt";    
static string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(txtList);    
static int x = file.Count();
string[,] list = new string[x ,5];

public void loadGuestList()
{

    int count2 = 0;
    foreach (string line in file)
    {
        string[] sliced = line.Split('|');
        int count = 0;

        list[count2, count] = sliced[0];
        count++;
        list[count2, count] = sliced[1];
        count++;
        list[count2,count] = sliced[2];
        count++;
        list[count2,count]= sliced[3];
        count++;
        list[count2, count] = sliced[4];
        count++;
        listBox1.Items.Add(list[count2,0]);
        count2++;
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string person in list)
    {
        if (  person[0].ToString()==listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            addTxt.Text = char.ToString(person[1]);
            textPhone.Text = char.ToString(person[2]);
            textPeople.Text = char.ToString(person[3]);
            if (person[4] == 'n' )
            {
            }
            else
            {
                chkRSVP.Checked = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us where the exception is occurring - or what you've tried to do to diagnose it. It would really help if you could show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - just as a console app. I suspect that while you try to write such an app to isolate the issue, you'll find the bug..

Comment: *"statement `person[0]==listbox1.selectedIndex` isn't returning true even though even though both are the same"* - you say **index**, in code you are using Selected**Item**. Could this be a problem?

Comment: listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString() ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
foreach (string person in list)
```

The list is defined as being `string[,]` which when you for each over will do every element, not just the column of data.  You really should do something such as:

```
for(int index = 0; index <= list.GetUpperBound(0); index++)
{
    string slice1 = list[index, 0];
    string slice2 = list[index, 1];
    ....
}
```

or switch to using a `Dictionary<string, string[]>()`.

Comment: Thanks i guess it was me trying to make things simple but made it alot more complicated in the end.   I ended up using a simple nested for loop to iterate through the multidimensional array and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a "Person" object and override equals(). Right now you're trying to put your multidimensional array (list[0]) into a string, it'll give you a unwanted result.  You should use list[0,0] instead.

Answer (score 0):

In agreement with Adam Gritt, I tested the following code and it seemed to work:

```
using System;

namespace so_foreach_bounds
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            //System.Text.StringBuilder newFile = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            string txtList= "guest_list.txt";    
            string[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(txtList);    
            int x = file.Length;
            System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]> list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]> ();

            foreach (string line in file)
            {
                string[] sliced = line.Split('|');
                list.Add(sliced);
            }

            foreach (string[] person in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (String.Join(", ", person));

                if (person[0] =="Gary")
                {
                    string txtAdd = person[1];
                    string txtPhone = person[2];
                    string txtpeople = person[3];
                    if (person[4] == "n" )
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bool has_resvped = true;
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is how you are iterating over the 2d array. It is usually a better idea to create a "Person" class, than try to manage it via arrays though. Oh yes, and it's usually a good idea to check that a list box item is selected before attempting to use one of its members.